# How to un delete a google cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

while deploying a Firebase cloud function, I have deleted previously deployed Cloud Functions,
Is there any way to revert or roll back this deployment and get previously deployed Cloud Function back??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't recover the deleted cloud function.

I tried to delete a cloud function from my Google Cloud Console and got this message before proceding.

[image]